# [Catalina home]/catalina.sh: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=: not found Tomcat (VM option) IntelliJ

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, virtual-machine, catalina, remote-connection

When I run Tomcat server with making vm option in "Edit configurations" it appear that error:

```
/`Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/bin/catalina.sh: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true: not found`
```

I find somewhere on the web advice to add something like this in catalina.sh:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

When I added that, error was changed on this:

```
/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/bin/catalina.sh: 118: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true: not found
/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/bin/catalina.sh: 119: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010: not found
/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/bin/catalina.sh: 120: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false: not found
/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/bin/catalina.sh: 121: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false: not found
/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/bin/catalina.sh: 122: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false: not found
/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=: not found
```

Addictionally appear yellow window:

```
Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: 
Unable to ping server at localhost:1099
```

When I delete my connection query from "vm options" in Tomcat configurations, that server start correctly.

Here is [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX6T7.png) of Run/Debug Configurations.

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot with your run configuration?

Comment: Ok, I added it now

Answer (score 1):

[RESOLVED] To do it, you need write in catalina.sh that:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```